# jQuery-powered show/hide link causes page to scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

Javascript and jQuery newbie here. I wrote a link in my homepage that's supposed to toggle the visibility of a block of text in a  element below it. Here's the html, followed by the Javascript block that implements the show/hide behavior.

```
<a href="#hh_bibtex">Show BibTeX</a>
<div class="bibtex" id="hh_bibtex">
  This text should appear and disappear.
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $("#hh_bibtex").hide();

  $("[href='#hh_bibtex']").click(function(){
    if ( $(this).html() == "Show BibTeX" ) {
      $(this).html("Hide BibTeX");
      $("#hh_bibtex").show();
    } else {
      $(this).html("Show BibTeX");
      $("#hh_bibtex").hide();
    }
  });

</script>
```

This works ok, except with one very annoying quirk: when I click the link to show the text block, not only does the text appear, but the page instantly scrolls down so that "This text should appear and disappear" is at the very top of the browser window. It's very disorienting. Mercifully, the opposite is not true: when I click the link to make the text disappear, the window does not scroll.

How can I eliminate this unwelcome scrolling?

Comment: Do you have a live example by any chance?

Comment: Have you set height for the class `bibtex`?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for doing a little follow up and providing the link where you found your answer.  For me the key was placing: `event.preventDefault()`; just right after the click event, and before executing my jquery .show() method.

```
 $("#playbuttonahref").click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
    $("#hiddenvideocontainer").show('slide', { direction: "left" }, 500);
    });
```